# design sync database mechanism for clients in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

how to serve a large database to the clients?
how to notify clients to update only the changes?
event better, how to provide this functionality with sync-mechanism?

**scenario:**
the scenario itself has some requirements I'll try to explain:

[image]

there is an offline database here that devices need to get for working offline independently.
clients only have to sync themself. some replication mechanism like **master-slave** .
the master can write data to DB and slaves only have to sync and read data .

I have two bottlenecks here:

1. database is about: 60 Mb but it can grow much more.
2. because of multi-platform use case : client's devices maybe be in macos , windows, andriod, ios

first I was using google-firestore for this purpose but our data is some kind of sensitive and we cannot use migration strategy in the future. so I created large sqllite db for clients and . the clients can download the database manually. **this is not right**. even with small updates, our clients have to download db again.

is it possible to create a self synced mechanism that backend notify clients for getting updates?

Comment: 60 MB SQLite database is no problem... there are folks with absolutely massive DBs out there.  The real issue I think is that you need a way to merge all of your data from offline clients.  Look into operational transform.  It's a complicated problem.

Comment: @Brad I had an idea,  we split the updates into chunks and clients get a list of updated files. these files have a timestamp inside theire name so after the sync mechanism they cache the file names and in next sync they know which files are downloaded. but this comes with a problem . there must be a validation and insertion strategy, to avoid future duplication rowns and so on. I was wondering if large databases can be split into chunks without any duplications.